# How to fetch JSON data in a Vue SPA?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I created a sample Vue application via `@vue/cli` 3.0:

```
vue create testapp
cd testapp
npm run serve
```

As part of `mounted()`, I wanted to `fetch` some local data:

```
fetch("users.json")
   .then(r => r.json())
   .then(r => this.users = r.hits.hits.map(x => x._source))
```

where `users` is defined in `data()`.

The response is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <title>example.com</title>
  <link href="/about.js" rel="prefetch"><link href="/app.js" rel="preload" as="script"></head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but example.com doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/app.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

I tried to move the JSON file to `static` in the root of the application (at the same level as `src`, then in `assets` and then everywhere I could think of - the answer is always the one from the app which assumes that this is a request for HTML/JS/CSS content, and not raw data.

**Where should such a static file be placed?**

Comment: It's probably less about where to put it, and more about what headers to serve alongside it. If you're serving `text/html` headers for the file it's gonna be treated as HTML.

Comment: @ceejayoz: this is a good point. I will look at how make `npm` serve specific headers for specific files. The accepted answer matches my usecase but the general solution would possibly be more useful if someone hits the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may assign the JSON into your data at the beginning, try this in your `App.vue`

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="user in users">{{user}}</div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import json from './users.json'
    export default{
        data(){
           return{
              users: json
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

And also make sure your `main.js` has import `App.vue`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

Locate your `users.json` at the same level as `src`(which is same with `App.vue`) is fine.

Hope this may help you! Cheers

Comment: This is a good idea when the file is fixed (and not, for instance, reloaded as part of the lifecycle of the application) - it matches my usecase, though. Thanks

Comment: Yeah @WoJ, if the file is dynamic probably `fs` is needed to do some r/w stuff. Anyway so glad that it matches your case, Cheers ;)